# Set Content type of FakeRequest (PlayFramework 2.1 - RC2)

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I want to set content-type of Fake Request (Play 2.1-RC2). Following code doesn't work (an action receives application/octet-stream instead of application/pdf)

```
route(FakeRequest(POST,
                  controllers.routes.FilesController.filesEndpointPost().url,
                  FakeHeaders(Seq(CONTENT_TYPE->Seq("application/pdf"))),
                  AnyContentAsRaw(RawBuffer(1000,"brokenpdf".getBytes))
                 )
     ).get
```

Comment: What is the value of CONTENT_TYPE ?

Comment: @cristian see https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/http/StandardValues.scala#L205

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works(content type remains application/pdf)(note: use this code to test actions processing binary streams):

```
route(FakeRequest(POST,
                  controllers.routes.FilesController.filesEndpointPost().url,
                  FakeHeaders(Seq(CONTENT_TYPE->Seq("application/pdf"))),
                  "brokenpdf"))
      (new Writeable({s:String => s.getBytes}, None)
     ).get
```

Comment: I wrote blog post about it http://chepurnoy.org/blog/2013/02/play-framework-v-2-dot-1-how-to-test-actions-processing-binary-streams/